# 15.10 Japanese input doesn't work

Tags: 15.10, ibus, input-language, japanese

I've tried to add Japanese input using [this](http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2014/05/25/japanese-input-on-ubuntu-linux-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr/) but it doesn't work for me.
After restart I've no ibus running (checked by `ps aux`) and no Japanese (Anthy) in text input settings.

My default locale is English.

Update: Mentioned method works on fresh system but I can't figure out why it doesn't with my installation.

Comment: Is IBus the selected input method system in Language Support?

Comment: Yes, of course it is.

Comment: What if you try to start ibus manually: `ibus-daemon -dx`? Also, can you please show us the output of `cat ~/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/RS3isFP4)'s content of `~/.xsession-errors`. I can't see anything related to ibus.

Also, I can't see difference too if I start ibus manually via `ibus-daemon -dx`.

Comment: Actually, ibus daemon starts (there are ibus stuff like ibus-daemon/-ui/anthy engine/etc in process list) but I can't see Anthy in text entry settings.
Maybe I can use it without adding another input source? Can I set hotkey or something for this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any applicable hotkey. But when in Text Entry, do you click the '+' button to look for Japanese (Anthy)?

Comment: Yes, I did. I understand why you're asking, but I've done exactly the same steps as in tutorial and checked several times. And I didn't get why it doesn't work since everything ok with fresh installation.

Comment: Your problem seems to be hard to debug. My last idea (a long shot) is to ensure that all packages which should be available are actually installed. You can do that with the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: One possible workaround is to select fcitx as input method system in Language Support, install the fcitx-anthy package (or probably better: fcitx-mozc), and restart the computer.

Comment: fcitx didn't start automatically either. But after some digging into its doc I found [this](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Input_method_related_environment_variables) and now I have working japanese input with some drawbacks. Firstly it was necessary to add fcitx to autostart manually and input indicator now missing.

Comment: Isn't the `im-config` package installed on your system?

Comment: I've `im-config` installed. And it even creates correct `.xinputrc ` in my `$HOME`

Comment: `im-config` should both start ibus/fcitx and create those variables. I'm lost. Anyway, good that you succeeded in finding a decent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's not a common problem and I have no idea why it doesn't work out of the box.

But after reading some [fcitx docs](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Input_method_related_environment_variables) I set all these envvars manually. Also I've to add fcitx to startup.

Now it works like expected. Maybe it'll help.

Thanks, Gunnar.

Answer (score 1):

I solved going on "Insert text configuration" (sorry, it's translated from italian), removed "Japanese" and added "Japanese (Anthy) (Ibus)"
See images below.

[image: configuration window]

Comment: I didn't have any ibus-related items in list as I mentioned in 1st post.

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTANT EDIT: It doesn't work correctly yet.

---

I've just made it work on 14.04. I installed Anthy and the fcitx-anthy wrapper, then ran im-config choosing fcitx. Now I have two icons representing the input mode, with the standard one being useless.

[image]

The new one with the keyboard does all it should though. And no problems so far.

EDIT

So it looks in action:

[image]

And still no Anthy here:

[image]

がんばって。

EDIT

It broke after a reboot. Now it doesn't convert and causes problems while typing, like no backspace. The conversion list doesn't show up.